# How do you calculate MTD/YTD Average Working Days Sales using MDX?

Tags: attributes, mdx, member

I’m not sure if this is possible or not but I’m trying to create a calculated member in our sales cube that will return the average working day sales (actuals).  Where working days is sum of the Working Days Rate.

In our date dimension I’ve added a Working Day Rate member attribute that has a different weighting per day. Mon-Friday 1, Sat 0.5, Sun 0, Holiday 0.

Below is some sample data.

```
Long Date   Day Name of Week    Working Day Rate    Actual  MTD Average Working Day Actual
May 1, 2020 Friday              1.00                $3,155  
May 2, 2020 Saturday            0.50                $9,849  
May 3, 2020 Sunday              0.00                $632    
May 4, 2020 Monday              1.00                $29,425 
May 5, 2020 Tuesday             1.00                $34,336 
May 6, 2020 Wednesday           1.00                $49,378 
May 7, 2020 Thursday            1.00                $35,446 
May 8, 2020 Friday              1.00                $44,828 
May 9, 2020 Saturday            0.50                $9,142  
May 10, 2020 Sunday             0.00                $653               $30,978 
                
Sum of Working Days             7.00                $216,844
[Sample Data][1]
```

What I am trying to create is a calculated member which will sum up the Actuals and divide by the Sum of the Working Day Rates for a specified date.
So in the above data sample the calculation would be:  $216,844 / 7.00 = $30,978.

Where I’m stuck with is how to write the MDX to do the Sum of the Working Day Rate.

I’ve seen many examples where people count days in a date dimension like below, but I’m looking to sum the member attribute values not count them.

```
Count (
        Descendants(
                    [Invoice Date].[Date - Hierarchy].Currentmember,
                    [Invoice Date].[Date - Hierarchy].[Day]
                    )
            )
```

Is it possible to do a Sum on member attribute in date dimension and use it in another calculation (or the same one) to find the average sales by working days?

I’d also like to be able to do the calculation on any date level if possible Day, Month Year.

[Date dimension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPvbh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution which uses a new Fact table based off of my date dimension. See link for solution explained:  https://intellixus.com/2011/08/15/fun-with-time-fact-tables/